# Не подгружается страница товара Opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: https, opencart, ssl

Установил для домена ssl сертификат. Начал настраивать магазин `opencart 2.3.0.2`, скачанный сразу с темой с англоязычного сайта. В общем теперь сайт работает на `https://`. При переходе на страницу товара загружается пустая страница. Думал вернуть все назад и убрать `ssl`, но не получилось. Помогите настроить `ssl` и чтобы при переходе по `http` редирект был на `https`.

Включил в `.htaccess` лог ошибок и вот что пишет:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   public_html/catalog/view/theme/tt_organica6/template/product/product.tpl
>   on line 722

в этой строчке вот что: `<?php echo $footer; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

По ошибке - трабл в файле шаблона, product.tpl. Парсер указывает не на вывод футера, а на конец файла. Проверьте, не использует ли создатель шаблона абсолютные пути или другие нестандартные методы передачи информации в шаблон (в этом файле).
И вы, наверное, отключили вывод ошибок в настройках магазина - включите и посмотрите, что там ещё пишет. Так же взгляните на лог (система-инструменты-журнал ошибок), он тоже может немного прояснить ситуацию.